# Arithmetic progression with complex common difference?

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

Suppose we have the following sequence:

$$\{0,i,2i,3i,4i,5i\}$$

Can we call this sequence an arithmetic progression with first term $0$ and common difference of $i$ ?

**Clarification:** Here, $i$ is referring to the imaginary unit, i.e., $i=\sqrt{-1}$

In general, I want to know if the common difference of an AP can be any complex value and not just real value.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see why not. In fact, those elementary formulae (the sum of $n$ terms, etc) can be applied.

Comment: @ajotatxe, I thought so too but lately I saw a few websites where they are suggesting that the common difference is restricted to reals, which is the reason for me asking this question.

Comment: @tom_cruise If you have a specific result in mind about arithmetic progressions, that might impose further restrictions. Else you can go as far as to have a group or even just a monoid.

Comment: An arithmetic sequence can be thought of as a set of (equally-spaced) points along a line in $ \ \mathbf{R}^2 \ \ $; the common difference between terms is related to the "slope" of the line.  One can perfectly well define a line in the complex plane in this fashion, except that the integer parameter corresponding to each point is not plotted on such a "graph".

Comment: @AlexR, The only result I have in mind is the sum of all values of the AP being a real value. I believe that doesn't impose any restrictions on the common difference, does it?

Comment: @tom_cruise The sum of a finite arithmetic progression can only be guaranteed to lie inside the monid $M$ it's start and increment belong to. For a finite progression of complex numbers with a real sum, you'll have some very strict constraints linking the number of terms, starting term and increment.

Comment: @AlexR, in my case, the number of terms is odd, so can't we create w.l.o.g the following AP: $\{a+j\delta\}_{j=-k}^{j=k}$ where $n=2k+1$ is the number of terms and $a,\delta$ are constant values with $\delta$ being the common difference. My question is: Is there necessarily any restriction on the domain of $\delta$ ?

Comment: @tom_cruise Well trivially, the sum will be $(2k+1)a$, so no. Confer my answer for a more complete characterisation given $a,\delta\in \mathbb C$ and $\{a+j\delta\}_{j=0}^n$ as the progression in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an arithmetic progression in any [monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) $(M,+)$. It is then defined by a starting element $a\in M$ and an increment $b\in M$ and the recursion
$$a_0 = a\\
a_{n+1} = a_n + b$$

There is no reason to restrict to reals $(\mathbb R,+)$ or complex numbers $(\mathbb C, +)$. For some results about arithmetic progressions, you might want $M$ to be an (abelian) group or even a field (both is true for the two settings mentioned here).

---

For a complex finite arithmetic progression $\{z,z+w, \ldots, z+nw\}$ to have a real sum, you must actually force
$$\Im \sum_{k=0}^n (z+kw) = \Im \left((n+1)z + \frac{n(n+1)}2w\right) = (n+1)\Im z + \frac{n(n+1)}2 \Im w \stackrel!=0$$
In other words you can freely pick the real parts of $z$ and $w$, but the imaginary parts must be related by
$$\Im w = - \frac2n \Im z$$
for some $n\in\mathbb N$ wich will double as the number of terms minus one (since we sum from $k=0$ to $n$, wich has $n+1$ summands)